# How to fix SSIS ForeEach error: 0x80131509

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs perfectly when I do it from DDTS VS 2015. But when deployed and use it on the same file. I get this error:

> Loop Each WorkSheet Named Loan Level Detail:Error: The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate.

I have given the login for SQL Agent full control both over the share and the NTFS folder security. I also changed the login to be the domain admin account and still get this error.

> OnPreValidate,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{B5E583F7-C754-4E7C-B149-1E2389FF1590},6/22/2021 1:23:51 PM,6/22/2021 1:23:51 PM,0,0x,

> OnPreValidate,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,
> OnPostValidate,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,
> PackageStart,MySSISServer,doman\User,MySSISPackage,{F3F62502-E070-4FB1-B32B-72C9E786F5F7},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,Beginning of package execution.

> OnPreExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Daily File Import,{F258FAE3-8F4E-4BCA-B862-A9A62C4BF932},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,
> OnPreExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop through each File xlsm file,{D3B28E26-3F1C-4B9C-8012-014491763916},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,
> OnPreExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop Each WorkSheet Named Loan Level Detail,{D4DB11FE-C65C-4AC5-BC9F-84BFCA135FB9},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:14 PM,0,0x,
> OnError,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop Each WorkSheet Named Loan Level Detail,{D4DB11FE-C65C-4AC5-BC9F-84BFCA135FB9},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-1073659869,0x,The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate.

> OnError,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop through each File xlsm file,{D3B28E26-3F1C-4B9C-8012-014491763916},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-1073659869,0x,The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate.

> OnError,MySSISServer,doman\User,Daily File Import,{F258FAE3-8F4E-4BCA-B862-A9A62C4BF932},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-1073659869,0x,The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach Enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "(null)". This occurs when the ForEach Enumerator cannot enumerate.

> OnPostExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop Each WorkSheet Named Loan Level Detail,{D4DB11FE-C65C-4AC5-BC9F-84BFCA135FB9},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnWarning,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop through each File xlsm file,{D3B28E26-3F1C-4B9C-8012-014491763916},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-2147381246,0x,SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

> OnWarning,MySSISServer,doman\User,Daily File Import,{F258FAE3-8F4E-4BCA-B862-A9A62C4BF932},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-2147381246,0x,SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

> OnPostExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Loop through each File xlsm file,{D3B28E26-3F1C-4B9C-8012-014491763916},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnWarning,MySSISServer,doman\User,Daily File Import,{F258FAE3-8F4E-4BCA-B862-A9A62C4BF932},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,-2147381246,0x,SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

> OnPostExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Daily File Import,{F258FAE3-8F4E-4BCA-B862-A9A62C4BF932},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnPreExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnPreValidate,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnPostValidate,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> OnPostExecute,MySSISServer,doman\User,Failure,{ae3b548a-2247-48fd-8fa3-bfe2fc76c823},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,0,0x,
> PackageEnd,MySSISServer,doman\User,MySSISPackage,{F3F62502-E070-4FB1-B32B-72C9E786F5F7},{85F2A211-60B3-4047-B1FA-8FAB1861938A},6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,6/22/2021 1:27:16 PM,1,0x,End of package execution.

Obviously, I have changed names and such but that is the log. Sorry for the length but I have found from previous experience the more info the better. @

For Billlinkc:
[image: Package]

The error happens at the "Loop Each WorkSheet..."

Comment: Please provide more details what you are doing with the SSIS Foreach Loop Container. Overall, it has many Enumerator Types.

Comment: This is the enumeration of a worksheet in an excel file.

Comment: In a related package, I am getting the error "Could not find part of the path" . This suggests permissions in both cases but the user for SQL Agent Service is SQLAdmin and it is in both the Administrators group, which is the owner of the entire path, and in the Domain Admins group. How could this not have permissions. I am missing something?

Comment: Is the referenced excel file a hard coded entity or do you use a foreach file enumerator to pick the current file? Can you post a screenshot of what your package looks like?

Comment: Billinkc, these are actually two problems I thought might be related. Both works in VS and not on the SQL Server they are deployed to, which is two different SQL Servers.